# How does unittest import modules?

Tags: python, scripting, directory, python-unittest

My directory structure:

```
r/
 |___init__.py
 |
 |_d1/
 |   |___init__.py
 |   |_s1.py
 |
 |_d2/
     |___init__.py
     |_test_s1.py
```

contents of s1.py:

```
def a():
    return 1
```

contents of test_s1.py:

```
from d1.s1 import a
from unittest import TestCase

class TestA(TestCase):
    def test_value(self):
        self.assertEqual(a(), 1)

print(a() * 10)
```

I navigate to directory `/r` and execute `python3 d2/test_s1.py`. I get an error `ImportError: No module named 'd1'`. How to execute script `test_s1.py`?
At the same time when I execute `python3 -m unittest discover` the unittest runs just fine and 10 (i.e. a() * 10) is printed.

Answer (score 0):

If want to explictly run tests in module test_s1 then can specify module or the full path to the script.

```
python3 -m unittest d2.test_s1
```

Or

```
python3 -m unittest d2/test_s1.py
```

As you mentioned, `python3 -m unittest discover` will auto-detect and run all test modules in the directory structure.

Note if "test_s1.py" had `if __name__ == '__main__':` at the end then the code block following would not be invoked since the main of unittest is being called and value of **name** in this case would be "d2.test_s1".